# only 347 bytes of Video Uploaded through CMS in PHP/MYSQL for clients

Tags: php, apache, video, file-upload, shared-hosting

I've created a basic CMS in PHP/MYSQL to allow videographers to manage their portfolio of videos. It's hosted on a shared server. A query inserts the video metadata into the db prior to the below upload script being carried out.

My upload script that works fine whenever I've tried it (on multiple machines, at my home and at University), but when a client tried to upload a video himself, the CMS only uploaded 347 bytes and then acted as though the upload was finished.

Is this an issue with my code or something on the client's end? Is there anything I can do to find out (I don't have access to the raw PHP/Apache logs...) Thanks!

This is the output of the linux "strings" command on the 347 byte binary file:

```
[moov
Srmra
\rmda
Drdrf
url 
/Crispy%20Revised%20SD%20h264%20web-desktop.m4v
rmdr
zrmda
Hrdrf
url 
3Crispy%20Revised%20SD%20h264%20web-iPhone-cell.3gp
rmdr
rmvc
mobi
urmda
Crdrf
url 
.Crispy%20Revised%20SD%20h264%20web-iPhone.m4v
rmdr
rmvc
mobi
```

This accounts for about 245 bytes of the 347.

Also, here is the core component of basic upload script (I've omitted some sanitizing activities):

```
if ($file["error"] > 0)
 {
  echo "<p>Return Code: " . $file["error"] . "</p>";
 }
else
 {
  if (file_exists($Dir.$file["propername"]))
   {
    echo "<p>".$file["propername"] . " already exists. ";
   }
  else
   {
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],
    $Dir.$file["propername"]);
    echo "<p>Stored in: " . $Dir.$file["propername"];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did you verify that it were the first few bytes of a video file? Maybe he simply uploaded just an `.rm` file? Do you have any code to validate the file format or check upload error conditions in $_FILES?

Comment: Client side validation of the file extension is what I've been doing. I also do if ($file["type"] == "video/quicktime") before launching the above function. So I guess the file was recognized as a quicktime mov, even at 347 bytes.

I Do not check upload errors, so that's something simple I should try...thanks.

Comment: Yeah, look into the 347 byte file and post what it contains

Comment: The media info in `$file[type]` is not reliable. It tells you what the browser assumes (or fakes) the content should be. You might want to verify with `mime_content_type()` as well.

Comment: Please see my edit in the main post for the string contents of the 347-byte file.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have problems with the php.ini upload-related directives.
You should check http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php this site for various solutions.